# Can a kind hearted tutor walk me through the code?

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I'm an absolute beginner in javascript. I've been practicing in edabit and while I was able to solve the exercise in question, I'm not sure if I really understand the logic behind the execution. If someone could walk me through the below code, especially the `if (newArr[i - 1] !== arr[i])` part?

What I really don't get is the `-1`. I kinda get that the loop iterates through `arr` and saves every element into `newArr` and then it eliminates the duplicates and pushes the unique numbers into array `z`. But I still don't get how does it do that?

The task was to create a function that sorts an array and removes all duplicate items from it. (I know that it could have been solved a lot easier, I just wanted to stick to a for loop).

```
function set(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    let z = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(arr[i])
        if (newArr[i - 1] !== arr[i]) {
            z.push(newArr[i])
        }
    } return z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you created two new variables:

```
let newArr = [];
let z = []
```

Then you enter a for-loop. This for-loop will iterate (add to) `i` until it is is no longer less then the length of the array `arr`.
`for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`
Inside the loop, the value of `arr[i]` is added to the `newArr`. The `i` is the number of the index of your array. Then, if the previous value of `newArr` is not equal to the current `arr` value, the `newArr` value is added to the `z` array.

After the loop is complete it returns the `z` array.

Comment: Thank you @carolyn savas for taking the time answering my question! By the **previous value** of `newArr` what do you mean exactly? Because as far as I can see it, up until the `if` condition the `arr` parameter and the `newArr` variable has the same items.